# php postfix sends no email

Tags: php, linux, debian, postfix-mta

I have PHP and Postfix installed. So if i try to send an email like that:

```
sendmail domain@somewhere.com < ip.txt
```

I get the Email. But if i try to send a mail via PHP `mail();`
I get the return value 1 but there is no message.

php.ini

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Here is my PHP Script: http://pastebin.com/3QUiJ79N

Comment: Fyi, php ignores the smtp settings on non-windows systems. You only need to set sendmail_path.

Comment: set to what? the .ini says it has it's default value set do sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `mail()` function returns 1 if the e-mail was dropped into the queue successfully. It can't verify that sendmail (or whatever you're using for transport) is configured correctly. Check your sendmail logs.

Comment: There is no mail.log in my /var/log :x

Comment: first i had, than i removed it. now i have postfix, which emulates sendmail i guess